# Uncaught ReferenceError: addTable_onclick is not defined,cannot figure it out

Tags: javascript

When I click the button,the browser shows the ReferenceError, I cannot find out anything tricky.

```
function addTable_onclick()
{
    var division=document.getElementById('field');
    for (var i=0;i<samples.length;i++)
    {
        if (!document.getElementById[samples[i]]) 
        {
            var htmlTable="<tr><td><input type="text" id=";
            htmlTable+=samples[i];
            for (var n=0;n<numbers.length;n++)
            {
                htmlTable+=" /></td><td><input type="text" id=";
                htmlTable+=samples[i]+numbers[n];
            }
            htmlTable+=" /></td>";
        }
    }
    division.innerHTML=htmlTable;
}


<input type="button" name="addTable" value="加一行" onclick="addTable_onclick()" />
```

Comment: Is your `addTable_onclick` function defined **inside** some other function, like a "ready" handler or something?

Comment: Show full error text

Comment: addTable_onclick() The problem is here. Add return to it's beginning.

Comment: @George Cao Where is the function defined? Internal script/External script.. where is it?

Comment: @AltayMazlum Add return at its beginning? why don't you correct and post the answer?

Comment: I copied and pasted it in my Visual Studio. And there are multiple mistakes in this code. What program are you using George?